# How to set an active css tab menu?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, tabs

I have a problem, I try to make menu tab using css, I got it, but the problem is I can't set an active tab menu without click the menu button, this is what i code:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
     tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
     tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
   }
```

```css
/*Tab*/
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0ff1e;
 color:black;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'antrian')">Antrian</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'semua')">Data</button>
  </div>

  <div id="antrian" class="tabcontent">
       <h3>Antrian</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="semua" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Semua</h3>
  </div>
```

I don't know how to modify the code to make the `"antrian"` tab to be an active tab without need to press the tab button first. Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Please use the `<>` icon to create a reproducible sample, including the call to `openCity`.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. A good example of the scenario you are facing will be helpful in others helping you better. Also, if you are only stuck in making "antrian" tab active initially, you should add an `active` class to it. You can toggle this `active` class based on the clicks or any other event you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'antrian')">Antrian</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'semua')">Data</button>
```

Replace your existing code with this code

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('antrian').className = '';
document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].className = 'active'

function openCity(event, city) {

  if (city === 'semua') {
    document.getElementById('antrian').className = 'tabcontent';
    document.getElementById('semua').className = '';
    document.getElementById('antrianBtn').className = '';
    document.getElementById('semuaBtn').className = 'active';
  }

  if (city === 'antrian') {
    document.getElementById('antrian').className = '';
    document.getElementById('semua').className = 'tabcontent';
    document.getElementById('antrianBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('semuaBtn').className = '';
  }

}
```

```css
/*Tab*/

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f0ff1e;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button id="antrianBtn" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'antrian')">Antrian</button>
  <button id="semuaBtn" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'semua')">Semua</button>
</div>

<div id="antrian" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Antrian</h3>
</div>

<div id="semua" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Semua</h3>
</div>
```